# simulation with kinetic friction, weird results

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I would like to simulate a point mass that is moving on a circular rail considering kinetic friction. The mass point starts at the bottom of the rail with an initial velocity v0. for the derivation of the algebraic differential equation system i used standard newtonian mechanics. fn is the normal force, that acts on the mass point and ϕ is the only degree of freedom. 
My computed solution behaves quite weird, e.g. the point mass never stops or it moves in a strange way (see Animation). Here is my code:

```
v0 := 14
m := 1
g := 9.81
μ := 0.05
R := 5
ϕ0 := 0
tmax := 50
eqn1[t_] := -fn[t] +m g Cos[ϕ[t]]^2 == -m R ϕ'[t]^2
eqn2[t_] := -μ Abs[fn[t]]*Sign[ϕ'[t]] -m g Sin[ϕ[t]] == m R ϕ''[t]
sol = NDSolve[{eqn1[t],eqn2[t], ϕ[0] == ϕ0, ϕ'[0] ==v0/R},
{ϕ,fn}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, MaxStepSize -> 0.001,AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6,InterpolationOrder -> All][[1]];
Plot[ϕ[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}]
Plot[fn[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[(fn[t] - g Cos[ϕ[t]]^2 - R ϕ'[t]^2) /. sol, {t,0,tmax},PlotRange -> All]
Plot[(-μ Abs[fn[t]]*Sign[ϕ'[t]] - g Sin[ϕ[t]]-R ϕ''[t]) /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
phi[t_] := ϕ[t] /. sol
Animate[ParametricPlot[{R*Sin[phi[t]], -R*Cos[phi[t]]}, {t, 0, tmax},Epilog ->{Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{R*Sin[phi[t]], -R*Cos[phi[t]]}]},PlotRange -> All, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0,tmax}, AnimationRunning -> False]`
```

How can I improve the code, so the simulation gets appropriate?

Comment: Do you have a problem in writing the equations, or in solving an ODE with Mathematica? In the first case, your question does not concern Mathematica and is off-topic; in the second, could you provide the ODE you want to solve and explain why you believe Mathematica is wrong at solving it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code can be improved in several ways. Here is my version, using `ListAnimate` instead of `Animate` to get better control of the individual frames. I also speed up the plotting by using `Circle` instead of `ParametricPlot`. This allows me to squeeze in $1000$ animation frames. The entire calculation is now done like this:

```
With[
 {v0 = 14,
  m = 1,
  g = 9.81,
  μ = 0.05,
  R = 5,
  ϕ0 = 0,
  tmax = 50},
 eqn[t_] := -μ Abs[m g Cos[ϕ[t]] 
    + m R ϕ'[t]^2  ]*Sign[ϕ'[t]] - m g Sin[ϕ[t]] == m R ϕ''[t];
 phi = NDSolveValue[{eqn[t], ϕ[0] == ϕ0, 
                   ϕ'[0] == v0/R}, ϕ, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.001, AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All];
 Column[{Plot[phi[t], {t, 0, tmax}],
   ListAnimate[
    Table[Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, R], {Red, PointSize[Medium], 
        Point[{R*Sin[phi[t]], -R*Cos[phi[t]]}]}}], {t, 0, tmax,tmax/1000}],
        AnimationRunning -> False]}]
 ]
```

[image: damping]

[image: movie]

In the differential equation, there was no need to have two equations because the normal force is really obtainable purely from $\phi$ alone. I also think you had a square in the normal force that doesn't belong there.

Comment: oh… i didn't see the square in equation for the normal force. thank you for mentioning!

Comment: one more question. For some reason the "faster"-button in the animation doesn't work. is it just me or why is that?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I basically never use those buttons because their behavior isn't intuitive, and instead adjust the rate by changing the `DefaultDuration` option and the number of frames.

Comment: didn't know about DefaultDuration. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

The solution is just fine, the problem here is `Animate` computing too few frames.

```
Monitor[frames = 
   Table[ParametricPlot[{R*Sin[phi[x]], -R*Cos[phi[x]]}, {x, 0, tmax},
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], 
       Point[{R*Sin[phi[t]], -R*Cos[phi[t]]}]}, PlotRange -> All, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, tmax, 0.1}], t];

 Export["test.gif", frames]
```

or

```
 ListAnimate[frames]
```

both work.

[image]

You might also try `Animate` with the `du` specified in the iterator.

Note we can speed the whole thing up by not regenerating the parametric plot for each frame, now `Animate` works pretty well.

```
p = ParametricPlot[{R*Sin[phi[x]], -R*Cos[phi[x]]}, {x, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
Animate[Show[{p, 
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Medium], 
     Point[{R*Sin[phi[t]], -R*Cos[phi[t]]}]}]}], {t, 0, tmax, 0.1}, 
 AnimationRate -> 1]
```